# Vuejs running "npm run build" randomly working

Tags: javascript, nginx, npm, vue.js

I've made a project and pushed it to Github. Now when I clone it to my local server everything works fine. But when I'm on my live server and run `npm run build` it sometimes works (1 out of 10 times). I'm using Ubuntu 16 with nginx and I'm using simple webpack with vue. I also have the latest node and npm on my server.

I don't get any errors and warnings. After executing the command correctly it usually show that build.js and build map is created but. Most of the times it show nothing it only show that it is busy with optimizing but I'm not getting any results.

What I mean with: "It is sometimes working" is e.g when I run 8 times in a row `npm run build` **WITHOUT** changing any code it is finally working.

I'm very new to the JavaScript tools and what I understand is `npm run build` is to build my project and create a build.js file for my live server while `npm run dev` is for localhost.

Does anyone know what is the problem?

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "front",
  "description": "A Vue.js project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "My name",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.3.3",
    "vue-authenticate": "^1.2.7",
    "vue-echo": "^1.0.1",
    "vue-resource": "^1.3.4",
    "vue-router": "^2.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.5.1",
    "cross-env": "^3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.0",
    "sass-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "vue-loader": "^12.1.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.3.3",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
  }
}
```

I don't know if this is relevant but this is my nginx block configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/my_project/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name my_project.com www.my_project.com

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you killing the process when it says it's busy optimizing, and then re-running?

Comment: No im not killing the process when its busy. This is the result when it is not working:  `> cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules

 92% chunk asset optimization` Usually when it working it also say something like created build.js and build.js.map

Answer (score 0):

I just reinstalled my VPS and its working now. I don't know what was wrong, maybe node was installed wrong but i don't know if that even possible.. anyway its working now!